# more efficient way to recode groups?

Tags: r

My goal is to recode group_old to look like group_desired:

```
group_old <- c(58,58,57,57,57,56,56,56,59,59,56)
group_desired <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,3)
df <- data.frame(group_old, group_desired)

> df
   group_old group_desired
1         58             1
2         58             1
3         57             2
4         57             2
5         57             2
6         56             3
7         56             3
8         56             3
9         59             4
10        59             4
11        56             3
```

I was able to do it:

```
codex <- data.frame(old = unique(df$group_old), new = 1:length(unique(df$group_old)))

df$group_new <- sapply(df$group_old, FUN = function(x) codex$new[codex$old == x] )

> df
   group_old group_desired group_new
1         58             1         1
2         58             1         1
3         57             2         2
4         57             2         2
5         57             2         2
6         56             3         3
7         56             3         3
8         56             3         3
9         59             4         4
10        59             4         4
11        56             3         3
```

However, this code runs very slowly on a dataset with 8 millions obs and 400k groups. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing for large data?

Comment: Here is an efficiency comparison between the answers provided so far, for a dataset with 180k obs and 7k groups. It's unclear whether these results will scale up linearly for my much larger dataset, though:

1) My original base R solution: 75 secs

2) My newer base R solution using within() and match(): 25 secs

3) Using dplyr's group_indices() function: 30 secs

4) Using dplyr's new recode() function: ??? (I'm having trouble updating dplyr again)

5) Using data.table: 25 secs

<b>Winner: tie between base R and data.table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

We group by `group_old`, and then create a new column by reference. `.GRP` is a special symbol in `data.table`. Its a simple grouping counter. It assigns 1 to the first group, 2 to the second.. and so on

```
group_old <- c(58,58,57,57,57,56,56,56,59,59,56)
df <- data.frame(group_old = group_old)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,group_desired := .GRP, by = group_old]

 #   group_old group_desired
 #1:        58             1
 #2:        58             1
 #3:        57             2
 #4:        57             2
 #5:        57             2
 #6:        56             3
 #7:        56             3
 #8:        56             3
 #9:        59             4
#10:        59             4
#11:        56             3
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
df$group_desired <- group_indices(df, group_old)
```

To get a similar result as above, we first define the factor levels for `group_old`:

```
df$group_old <- factor(df$group_old, levels = unique(df$group_old))
df$group_desired <- group_indices(df, group_old)
```

**Note**: `group_indices` assigns group numbers based on ascending order (in case of numbers) or factor level (if the variable used is factor).

Comment: Thanks, your data.table solution works even though I don't quite understand the code (and I haven't tested the speed yet).

Question about your dplyr solution: It doesn't seem to work for me. Following your exact code, it spits out "3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 4 4 1" rather than what's desired. This happens regardless of whether I coerce group_old to be numeric or factor.

Comment: @gnotnek, check my update. I am sure there is a better way to use `group_indices`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about performance, but you could try recode from the new version of dplyr package:

```
df$group_desired <-
  dplyr::recode(df$group_old, `58` = 1, `57` = 2, `56` = 3, `59` = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do you get the newest dplyr? I thought I had the newest version but it has no such function "recode". I'm using RStudio.

Also, is there a way to generalize the second argument of recode() without manually specifying each value? Otherwise it doesn't work for any large data.

Comment: In RStudio, go to Tools -> Check for Package Updates or in the Packages Pane, click Update

Comment: I am not sure about generalization, need to play with it a bit more. If you come up with something please post.

Answer (score 0):

A more general data.table approach.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(old = LETTERS[1:6], new = 1:6)

set.seed(1234)
dt2 <- data.table(old = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 6, replace = TRUE))

setkey(dt1, old)
setkey(dt2, old)

dt2[dt1]
#    old new
# 1:   A   1
# 2:   B   2
# 3:   C   3
# 4:   D   4
# 5:   D   4
# 6:   D   4
# 7:   D   4
# 8:   E   5
# 9:   F   6
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered another Base R way that's a bit faster than my original:

```
df <- within(df, { group_new <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$group_old)) }  )
df <- within(df, { group_new <- match(group_new, unique(group_new)) }  )
```